# Lamp panel::Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lamp

Hi I just install ubuntu 10.04.
I use to use wamp server on windows that have manager panel.
Is lamp have such panel, or I have to time manually?
Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Probably a question for superuser though.

To restart your server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I made it,and its works. its not the probem.
I asking if lamp have manager GUI monitor like wamp server